# How to set a Gradient or an Image as TitleBar or Shell Background in MAUI application

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-maui

I was trying out .NET MAUI to get more comfortable with the framework. But, I encountered one problem while I was trying to set an image as a background of `TitleBar` / `AppBar` / `ActionBar`.

**First**, I have tried to add `Shell.Background` property and set it value to *title_bar.png (which is located inside Resources > Images folder)* like

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
        <Setter Property="Shell.Background" Value="title_bar.png" />
        ....
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

in *Resources > Styles > Styles.xaml* file. But, it was not working.

Then I was searching for a solution and I found [this github issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13066) in Xamarin.Forms repo.

**After that**, I was trying to set a gradient as a background of TitleBar / AppBar / ActionBar but it was also not working. More specifically changing the project's *Resources > Styles > Styles.xaml* file's "Shell.BackgroundColor" property's Value to any color is working but when I am trying to set the value like

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
        ...
        <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource TitleBarGradient}, Dark={StaticResource TitleBarGradient}}" />
        ....
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

but it's also not working *(Background changed to white)*.

I have added the below lines of code in *Resources > Styles > Colors.xaml* file

```
</ResourceDictionary>
    ...
    <LinearGradientBrush
        x:Key="TitleBarGradient"
        EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientStop
            Color="{StaticResource Yellow100Accent}"
            Offset="0.1" />
        <GradientStop
            Color="{StaticResource Blue200Accent}"
            Offset="1.0" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So, my question is am I doing something wrong or it's a bug or missing feature?

Comment: I have tried to test your code and met the same probelm. You can try to use the custom renderer to set the toolbar's background image on each platform.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the idea. I will try your suggested approach if that work I will post that as **a temporary** answer, and in the meanwhile, if the issue gets resolved _(maybe not soon)_. I will mark the answer as accepted.